# How to disable touch event in AR foundation (arkit)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm not very good with Unity especially in AR, but I finally built my first AR game.  However, there is one issue: when I place my game objects on the plane, I want them to be still and want them to move when I touch the display.   Is there a way to disable the touch hit or whatever it is called? 
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    enter code here

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(ARRaycastManager))]

public class PlaceOnPlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Instantiates this prefab on a plane at the touch location.")]
    GameObject m_PlacedPrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// The prefab to instantiate on touch.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject placedPrefab
    {
        get { return m_PlacedPrefab; }
        set { m_PlacedPrefab = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The object instantiated as a result of a successful raycast 
    intersection with a plane.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject spawnedObject { get; private set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        m_RaycastManager = GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>();
    }

    bool TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition)
    {
       #if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            touchPosition = new Vector2(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
            return true;
        }
else
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            return true;
        }
#endif

        touchPosition = default;
        return false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition))
            return;

        if (m_RaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, s_Hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
        {
            // Raycast hits are sorted by distance, so the first one
            // will be the closest hit.
            var hitPose = s_Hits[0].pose;

            if (spawnedObject == null)
            {
                spawnedObject = Instantiate(m_PlacedPrefab, 
           hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
            }
            else
            {
                spawnedObject.transform.position = hitPose.position;
            }
        }
    }

        static List<ARRaycastHit> s_Hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();

    ARRaycastManager m_RaycastManager;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any scripts for object interaction? If so, can you also share the code you are using?

Comment: Hello @KBaker I just uploaded the script.

Comment: So what is the current behaviour? You tap on the screen and it is placed but it is also moving?

Comment: actually i used a button to place the object so no need for the tap. When i press the button it places object on the surface, I want the touch to be disabled, because whenever i touch the display the object move around with my finger. i want the the object to be still, and not move when i touch the display.  @KBaker

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please for code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your comments, if you are placing the object with the button, all you need to do right now is to disable this script that you have attached here. The object should not be moving since what causes its movement is this code bit in `Update`:

```
spawnedObject.transform.position = hitPose.position;
```

You can either comment out this part or deactivate the script, both should work fine.